# Executing a select query stored as a Varchar in another table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can I execute a select query stored as a `Varchar` in another table's column ??.

Suppose there is a table `TB_SQL_QUERIES`, with column name as `SQL_QUERY_TEXT` and `ID`.

Is there a way to execute a query from this table where ID=(to be input by the user)

Comment: Yes, there is. Go read about EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do something like:

```
DECLARE
  l_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT sql_query_text INTO l_sql
      FROM tb_sql_queries
     WHERE id = 1;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END;
```

See [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Inprovising on the other answer about `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` :

Firstly, in 12c, you can have 32767 for SQL rather than the limitation of 4000 in prior versions. Thus, you can eliminate the effort to have multiple variables to keep concatenating the dynamic string whenever it exceeds 4000 characters.

Secondly, since you mentioned that the input would be by user, you need to have `Bind variable` to get the value at run time.